# Difference between two mysql query

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

I have two query like below.
First one returning 757 data
and second one returning 545 data

Here I am not getting where is the difference between two query.
I used first one for optimize query execution time

```
 SELECT supul.user_point_log_used_id, supul.point
                FROM user_point_used_logs supul
                    left join user_point_logs supl
                    on supul.user_point_log_id=supl.return_id
                    and supl.return_id is null
```

And Another one

```
SELECT user_point_used_logs.user_point_log_used_id, user_point_used_logs.point
            FROM user_point_used_logs
            WHERE user_point_log_id NOT IN (
                SELECT DISTINCT return_id
                FROM user_point_logs
                WHERE return_id IS NOT NULL
            )
```

**[FIDDLE LINK](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pSYWaJdyjKJxWSywvExLfy/4)**

Comment: This [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pSYWaJdyjKJxWSywvExLfy/3) does not have a parse error a select was missing a semicon (`;`).. Keep in mind it is imporant that if you provide a example that it "works"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `where supl.return_id is null`

your 2nd query act as a `inner join` 
- since you use `supl.return_id is null in ON clause` with `left join` in your first query it gives you all results of your first table 
- and that's why the result is different

```
SELECT supul.user_point_log_used_id, supul.point
                FROM user_point_used_logs supul
                    left join user_point_logs supl
                    on supul.user_point_log_id=supl.return_id
                    where supl.return_id is null
```